# Having map markers appear/disappear at certain zoom levels

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am making an app that plots a lot of unique markers to a map fragment (60 markers)/ I use an ArrayList for this and a for loop to plot them.

The problem I have is that whilst zoomed out, the map is very cluttered, and is laggy. I want to find a way to have the markers disappear on zooming out, e.g at level 11, and zooming back in from 10. How would I do this?

```
// Get a handle to the xml Map Fragment
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

ArrayList<LatLng> tree = new ArrayList<LatLng>()

tree.add(new LatLng(48.617515, -3.945385));
tree.add(new LatLng(49.617515, -3.945385));
... //x58

for (int i = 0; i < camLoc.size(); i++) {      //for loop to add the LatLng data to the array list
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(camLoc.get(i)));         
 }
}
```

Comment: update your markers when `onCameraChanged` is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has released a library that, when setup, will automatically cluster the markers when zoomed out. It is part of the Google Maps Android API Utility Library, [available here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/). You can find the setup guide for the [clustering here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering). I have personally used this in my app (after months of trying to setup other libraries) with much success. However, there is a bit of delay when clustering/declustering many items (I have over 1000 items on my map though, so you probably won't have the same issue).

It is important to note that you will need to create a custom implementation of `ClusterItem` and pass those objects through to the clusterer, instead of setting up markers directly through the `GoogleMap`.